NgRx Signal Store is not updating the state
Scenario: I need to make a kanban board with ToDo, In-Progress and Done items. The user should be able to drag and drop items around in different swimlanes, create new to-do items and remove items. I am using signals for Reactivity and NgRx SignalStore for state management.
My app.component.ts looks like this:
<app-to-do-card (onDragStart)="showData($event)"></app-to-do-card>

 <app-implementing-card [droppedItem]="droppedItemFromTodoToInProgress"
   [droppedItemFromDone]="droppedItemFromDone"
    (onDragInProgressStart)="sendDataToToDoList($event)"></app-implementing-card>

This is my app-to-do-card card:
@for (item of allItems();  track item){

<div pDraggable dragEffect = "move"
(onDragStart)="dragStart(item)" 
(onDragEnd)="dragEnd()"

class=" p-2 w-10 h-2 text-sm opacity-80 border-1 border-round border-200 shadow-3 hover:shadow-8  ">       

<h5>{{item.id}} - {{item.name}}</h5>
<p>{{item.status}} - {{item.description}}</p>   
</div>
}
</div>
<app-new-item (onItemAdded)="displayNewItems($event)"></app-new-item>

displayNewItems($event : Item[])
 {
   this.allItems.set($event);  
 }

This is my app-new-item component:
addNewItem()
 {
  let newItemDescription = this.newItemForm.controls['description'].value;
  let newItemName = this.newItemForm.controls['name'].value;

  let newItem : Item = 
  {
   id: (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)).toString(), //Random ID Assigned to each Item
   name: newItemName, 
   description: newItemDescription,
   status: TaskStates.ToDo
  }
this.store.addItem(newItem);
this.newItemForm.reset();
this.onItemAdded.emit(this.store.items())

 }

This is my store:

export const AllItemStore = signalStore
(
  { providedIn: 'root' },
  
  withState(ItemState),

  withMethods((store)=>
    ({
        addItem(newItem : Item): void
        {
            patchState(store, {items: [...store.items() , newItem]} )
            //console.log(state) //shows items inside state added successfully
        },
        getAllItems(): Item[]
        {
          return store.items(); //returns []
        },

        updateItemStatus(itemId: string, status: TaskStates) : void
        {
          //...store.items() is empty array []
          patchState(store, {items: {...store.items() , }})
          return ItemState.items.map((item)=>
            {
              return item.id === itemId ? {...item, status: status} : item
            })
        }
    }))
);

Problem:
My updateItemStatus is not working. I am not able to get the list of all items currently in store to perform a search by Id and update the status to In-Progress/Done. Both getAllItems and updateItemStatus are returning empty array [] eventhough addItems is properly setting the state with new items.
PS: I am using Angular 17 and all components are standalone.

Make sure you are calling this.store.updateItemStatus(...) from a component. If you call it from a service, it doesn't work. I haven't figured out why but that solves the issue.

I am calling it from a component not a service.
